# Running two endless parallel loops

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to run two endless parallel loops. One is reading data from a server and updates an object with a number. The other is doing nothing else then reading it and in case of change, processing it. Does not have to be in sync or so. So my questions are :

- In case of write from one side and read from another, does Python have issues with it ?
- In case I get a sync problem, do I need to lock the read/write processes ? Any other way 
  I should do it ?
- What is best to use, thread or threading ?
- As the next step, I will read from 100 sites and update 100 objects, 
  and read from 100 loops for the changes. Is it recommend to use Multiprocessing from the 
  beginning so I can scale without problems ?  Do I need at the read and write issues ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You will use Python, is it correct? I have add python language tag.

Comment: If it's possible to merge both tasks into a single loop, it's much simpler than using threads.

Comment: no, it is not recommend to merge in one loop. Both sides are totally asynchron so one is for listening, one for processing. So now I have 100 sites for listening and 100 for processing. All have different execution times.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, whatever you think will be understandable for you.
Meaning, your code should make sense to you for learning purposes..

Here's an example, it's light and easy to use.
Getting values from and to the thread is easy..
It's not actual multi-threading tho (same CPU core)

```
from threading import *

class worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, input=0):
        self.input = input
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            self.input += 1

x = worker(-100)
y = worker(x.input)

print y.input
```

This is just an example to show that the `Y` thread can access the data in `x`.. in practice this can be dangerous considering that both threads will be updating the same variable :)  (In short: -100 will be calculated twice per cycle, -98, -96, -94.. etc)

- Will not span across multiple CPU's
- Easy to use ( accessing data across threads is easy )
- Logical code, if you're not familar with queue systems or distributed systems
- Will raise a error if the OS can't create more threads (a "limitation")

Comment: "It's not actual multi-threading tho" - but it is! The limitation says that only one at once can execute Python code. But outside Python calls all can happen

Comment: All i know is that, exuting this code will create asyncron code that can execute in "paralell" to each other but it will not span across multiple CPU's, which in fact doesn't create multi-processed applications in a hardware sense.. but you will be able to run software(os)-multithreaded codeblocks :) It works, bottom line :)

Comment: The `multiprocessing` module uses OS processes, while `threading` uses OS threads. Both can take advantage of multicore machines (unless you're using `threading` and Global Interpreter Lock comes in the way).

Comment: Thanks, my only concern is that one processor runs at 100% and the rest is idle. So what is recommend to use ?

Comment: I'd say `multiprocessing` is the way to go, it's probably the only way you'll be able to actually utelizing the different cores (or what you refer to as processors) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

class producer(Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue=queue
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            self.queue.put(update_value())

class consumer(Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue=queue
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            value = queue.get()
            do_whatever_you_want(value)
queue = Queue()
producer(queue)
consumer(queue)
```

notice that you can scale by using 100 producer and one consumer (and of course one queue) 100 threads should be ok but things would be different if you wanted 10000

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will do some test. The concept is that one side is listening to 100 server, get the data and update the related objects. The other side is just running in a loop to read and process data. I am still unsure if multiprocessing the not better, when the processor runs at 90% ? Any advice ? How  is the system reacting when update and readin happens at the same time, is it crashing ? This is my biggests concern.

Comment: if you have multicore and multiprocessing is better if the process is CPU bound the queue are used similarly see http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes there is lock under so there is guaranty that reading and writing can't happen simultaneous if the process heavy is in the consumer side you can have several process consuming the same queue